# Application does not show up in Android Market for Motorola XOOM tablet

Tags: android, google-play, android-3.0-honeycomb

We have an android application, manifest of which sets the following configurations:

```
minsdkVersion = "4"

<supports-screens 
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="false" />
```

However, when a user with Motorola XOOM device browses Android Market he is not displayed our application.

Why is this so?

Answer (score 24):

I had the same issue.  Along with including `android:xlargeScreens="true"` I found this to be the fix.

> The Android Market treats as though requesting a permission like CALL_PHONE also requests:
>
> `<uses-feature
>   android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
>   />`
>
> The XOOM does not have telephony —
>   the first Android Market-compliant
>   device with that limitation. While it
>   can have a data plan, it has no voice
>   or SMS capability, and so it is
>   treated as not having
>   android.hardware.telephony. But, if
>   you request permissions like
>   CALL_PHONE, the Android Market by
>   default will assume you need
>   android.hardware.telephony. As a
>   result, you will be filtered out of
>   the Market for the XOOM.
>
> The solution is simple: for any
>   hardware features that might be
>   implied by permissions but that you do
>   not absolutely need, manually add the
>   appropriate  element to
>   your manifest with
>   android:required="false":
>
> `<uses-feature
>   android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
>         android:required="false" />`

From this blog:
[The CommonsBlog - XOOM, Permissions, and the Android Market](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/02/25/xoom-permissions-android-market.html)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have copy protection turned on?
I had a similar problem, some Xooms could see my app, but some couldn't.
Apparently, turning on copy protection (in the post-upload app settings) can block some devices from viewing/downloading the app.  If that's what's causing the problem, simply turning off copy protection will fix the issue. Google recommends you use the licensing service instead to protect your apps: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html

Answer (score 1):

The XOOM has an extra large screen so you need `android:xlargeScreens="true"` in your manifest.

**Edit**: Seems like this defaults to true. See my comment below.

Comment: As per :http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.htmlAs a general rule, Market assumes that the platform on the device can adapt smaller layouts to larger screens, but cannot adapt larger layouts to smaller screens. Thus, if an application declares support for "normal" screen size only, Market makes the application available to both normal- and large-screen devices, but filters the application so that it is not available to small-screen devices.

Comment: Does the above not mean that if a device has largeScreen="true" then xlargeScreen is supported too?

Comment: The docs @khotmanish mentioned are a little ambiguous since the first sentence says _larger_, implying both large and xlarge, while the second sentence says just _large_.

Comment: Seems I am wrong. The default value for all the `supports-screens` attributes are true if minSdk or targetSdk is >= 4. As per: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Answer (score 1):

Remember!

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="X" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

targetSdkVersion will take care of you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do you request any telephony permissions in your app, e.g. `READ_SMS` or `CALL_PHONE`?  If so, then the Market will infer that telephony support is required, which means it won't be available for the Xoom.

If this is the case, then you need to update your AndroidManifest.xml to make the telephony features optional:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
```

You'll also need to make sure your app copes gracefully when the telephony features aren't present!

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420228/android-market-filters-app-telephony/8494994#8494994) for more detail on how to check what devices the Market is offering your app on.

The `android:xlargeScreens="true"` permission is not required, unless you've explicitly included the `[supports-screens][2]` in your AndroidManifest.xml (which you shouldn't, as the default will make it available on all screen sizes).